# Override view (from other package), fix browser layers priority

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a `other.package` registering a view `my_view`. Then I'm trying to replace this view with a view defined in mine `this.package`.

```
  <browser:page
    for="other.package.interfaces.IBarClass"
    name="my_view"
    class="this.package.views.FooClass"
    permission="zope2.View"
    layer="this.package.interfaces.IThisPackageContentLayer"
    />
```

For some reason `my_view` is not overrided. I think its about layers priority maybe, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any suggestion?

If I rename the view (`name="my_view_new"`) it is working as expected. But if the same name is used, the original one seems to have priority. How can I change this?

**UPDATE**:
It's about layer priority:

```
(Pdb) self.request.__provides__.__iro__[13]
<InterfaceClass other.package.interfaces.layer.IOriginalLayer>
(Pdb) self.request.__provides__.__iro__[14]
<InterfaceClass this.package.content.interfaces.IThisPackageContentLayer>
```

> You can check the activated layers from HTTP request object by looking
>   at self.request.**provides**.**iro**. Layers are evaluated from zero
>   index (highest priority) the last index (lowest priority). [(source)](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/layers.html#debugging-active-layers)

So, the problem is how can I prioritize a layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by fixing the layers' priority this way:

```
class IThisPackageContentLayer(IOriginalLayer):
```

as suggested [here](https://community.plone.org/t/how-to-change-layers-priority/7311/2).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is, to use ZCML-Overrides with the same browser layer.
That should also override the original, but the solution with sub classing the original layer is a bit nice ;).